# How to force Power Automate select to output an Integer

Tags: power-automate

I have a Power Automate, and as part of it I am doing a Select on an array and mapping new fields/values.

It used to be that this Select would output integers for 2 fields `OrderedSalesQuantity` and `SalesPrice`. I modified the Power Automate to add 2 new fields and ever since, it is now outputting strings for those fields. I have checked previous runs and they were fine, and even checked previous versions to make sure I didn't change anything else.

I added int(item()?['field']) to try to force it but it still outputs string. See related images. I would like to get a JSON object from it which has those fields as integers.

[image: power automate image]
[image]

Comment: Interesting, your scenario works for me.  If I have an array of numbers, some defined as a string value, others as an integer, if I wrap it in the `int()` expression, it converts it successfully.  Is there anything else you can provide re: data maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created one sample flow and it seems working fine with one minor tweak:

**Step 1:**

> Convert the int array assignment to the `text mode` as below screenshot and make sure there is no excessive quotes around the formula.
> [image]

**Step 2:**

> In `Parse Json` action - set that field type as `integer`
> [image]

This gave me result as below:

[image]